# Compound query with two "orderby" clause doesn't work in Firestore, Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch the most popular posts from the last 24 hours from Firestore in Android. Unfortunately, the second "orderby" clause of my compound query doesn't take effect and query orders the posts from last 24 hours based on time not on rating. I have created compound index in Firestore.

```
 Query first = db.collection("posts")
                .whereEqualTo("country_code",sharedpreferences.getString("country_code",""))
                .whereGreaterThan("time", twentyFourHoursAgo)
                .orderBy("time")
                .orderBy("rating", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will *first* order the documents on time, and secondary on rating. So only if two documents have the same time, will the one with the highest rating come first.

Are you saying that is not what you're seeing?

---

If that is what you are seeing, but not what you want, this is unfortunately an effect of how Firestore handles queries - and the only way it can meet its performance guarantees (at the moment). So if you actually want to sort by score, you'll have to reorder them in your application code once you've let Firestore do the filtering on time.

For some use-cases you can consider adding a field that simply flags for your first filter, but that seems unlikely for your use-case. A case I recently answer where it doesn't apply is where somebody had a `stockCount` field and only wanted items that are in stock, ordered by price. By introducing a `isInStock` field that you also update when you increment/decrement stock, you can then use an equality filter to determine what's in stock and the `orderBy` can then be on the field you actually care about. But as said, that doesn't seem feasible here as your `time` field likely never changes.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Frank. Actually, I don't need to sort by time here. I can simply sort by score. But Firestore forces to sort by the same field after whereGreaterThan clause. Am I doing something wrong ?  In the other hand, reordering them in application code means I have to reorder 10k posts in local if I have 10k posts today.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, but you can't build the exact query in Firestore without changing your data, which seems unreasonable here. Retrieving 10K documents seems unreasonable too though, as it is unlikely that most users will view that many. I'd strongly suggest to reconsider that and retrieve a more reasonable number of documents that the user is more likely to actually look at. Either way, you'll have to reorder them on the client, unless somebody else posts an answer that doesn't require that.

Comment: I decided to add an  `isTimePassed` field like you mentioned and update its value with a continuous function.

Comment: Oooh, nice! I didn't think that would be feasible here, but if it *is* that is indeed a great solution. If you'd like to learn more about why Firestore doesn't support what may at first seem like basic queries, I recommend checking Todd's excellent video on the topic: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI